# Conversion from dBm to dB\$\mu\$V?

Tags: rf, math, decibel

I am trying to derive the conversion from dBm to dB\$\mu\$V. So, please correct me If I am wrong.

\begin{align}
\textrm{dBm} 
&= 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{P}{1\textrm{mW}} \right) = 10 \log(P) + 30 \\
&= 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{ V^2}{Z} \right) + 30\\
&= 10 \log_{10} \left( V^2 \right) - 10  \log_{10}(Z) + 30\\
&= 20 \log_{10} \left( V \right) - 10  \log_{10}(Z) + 30\\
&= 20 \log_{10} \left( \frac{V}{1\mu V} 10^{-6} \right) - 10  \log_{10}(Z) + 30\\
&= \underbrace{20 \log_{10} \left( \frac{V}{1\mu V} \right)}_{\textrm{dB}\mu V} + \underbrace{20\log_{10}\left( 10^{-6} \right)}_{-120} - 10  \log_{10}(Z) + 30\\
&= \textrm{dB}\mu V -120 - 10  \log_{10}(Z) + 30\\
&= \textrm{dB}\mu V -90 - 10  \log_{10}(Z) \\
\Leftrightarrow \\
\textrm{dB}\mu V &= \textrm{dBm} + 90 + 10  \log_{10}(Z)
\end{align}

Comment: do a quick mental check: let Z=1Ω, so \$10\log_{10}Z = 0\$. let your signal power be 1 milliwatt = 0 dBm. Does 90 dBµV make sense? What's the voltage over 1Ω if you spend 1 mW?

Comment: V = \$\sqrt{P Z} = 1mV\$?

Comment: In this "cheat sheet", they have simply conversion relation but no derivation for instance. http://www.aaronia.com/fileadmin/media-archive/conversion_formulas.pdf

Comment: No, 1 mW is not equivalent to 1 mV @ 1Ω.

Comment: my bad, it should be \$ V = \sqrt{10^{-3} 1} = 0.0316227766 \$!?

Comment: And what is 90 dBuV equivalent to? Do we have to spoon-feed you every step of the way?

Comment: Of course 90 dBuV is same as the above in linear domain, i.e., 0.0316227766. However, my question was about the derivation on the relationship between dBm and dBuV. This exercise that we are doing is only verifying the result, to my eyes (if you know what it means). We all see things differently, fair enough and respect that. I had a humble request on the derivation of the relationship between dBm and dBuV. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: We gave you the derivation. I really did exactly that in my comment. There's nothing more than the methodology I've illustrated in that comment. If you can't do it based on that, you need to learn basics of dB, voltages and powers, not someone to do your homework for you, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dBm is short for dBmW.  The measurement is milli-watts.

dBuV is short for dbuV.  The measurement is in micro-volts.

In order to convert from volts to watts you have to assume some sort of impedance.

For a free space propagation of an RF signal we assume the impedance of free space (which is 376.73 ohms).

Voltage and power are related as follows...

W = V^2 / Z

Or

V = sqrt(W * Z)

Assuming a 1mW signal and Z = the impedance of free space we get...

V = sqrt(0.001 * 376.73) = 0.61378

in db-volts this is...

dBV = 20 * log10(0.61378) = -4.2dBV

To convert dBV to dBuV we just multiply by 1 million (so add 120dB)

-4.24dBV = (-4.2 + 120)dBuV = 115.8dBuV

Therefore 1dBmW = 115.8dBuV when Z = 376.73 ohms

This matches the conversion chart you linked to.

Your derivation above comes up with the same answer if you put in 376.73 ohms for Z.

dBuV = dBm + 90 + 10*log(376.73) = dBm +90 + 25.8 = dBm + 115.8

Comment: "dBm is short for dBmW/m^2". No it is short for dBmW. m^2 is not implicit. If you measure the power going to an antenna, there is no m^2 involved, just power. If you want dBmW/m^2, use that. "dBuV is short for dbuV/m^2" Again, No. dBuV is not short for dBuV/m^2. While mW/m^2 is at least a sensible unit, V/m^2 is not. V/m however is, and represents electric field strength. So dBuV/m is also a sensible unit.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I agree with you, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use 0.632 volts PeakPeak for 50 ohms and one milliWatt; or 0.223 volts RMS for 50 ohms.

Makes thinking about systems a much easier task.

This comes from using one of the Watts Law forms: P = V^2/R

Given that, what is the RMS voltage for -100dBm in a 50 ohm system? (which is -130 dB Watt or -130 dBW)

What is 100 dB down from 0.223 volts RMS?

what is 0.223 / 100,000? Its 2.23 microVolts RMS.